# la redirección me actualiza todas las vistas laravel + vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Estoy trabajando con Laravel 6 y Vuejs junto con broadcasting.

Tengo una vista con un formulario donde un usuario ingresa sus datos y, en tiempo real, con una transmisión, un usuario administrador valida esos datos y redirige al usuario a otra vista. Casi todo funciona bien. El problema es que la vista del administrador también se redirige y no quiero que eso suceda.

todo comienza aquí en la vista del usuario

```
<form method="post" v-on:submit.prevent="validarCodigo">
              <!-- Heading -->
              <h3 class="dark-grey-text text-center mt-4">
                <strong>Validador Instagram:</strong>
                {{-- <label for="">VALOR: {{$usuario->id}}</label> --}}
              </h3>
              <hr>

              <input type="text" :value="usuario_id='{{$usuario->id}}'" hidden>
              <div class="md-form">
                <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
                <input v-model="email" type="email" id="form2" class="form-control">
                <label for="form2">Correo Electrónico</label>
              </div>
              <div class="md-form">
                <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt prefix grey-text"></i>
                <input v-model="celular" type="text" id="form3" class="form-control">
                <label for="form3">Celular</label>
              </div>
              <div class="md-form">
                <i class="fas fa-key prefix grey-text"></i>
                <input v-model="codigo" type="text" id="form4" class="form-control">
                <label for="form4">CÓDIGO RECIBIDO</label>
              </div>

              <div class="text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-indigo">Validar</button>
                <hr>
              </div>
```

El formulario lleva a validar los datos y guardarlos en el bd hasta bloquear la pantalla hasta que el administrador valide los datos

```
validarCodigo: function(){

        var url = '/acceso';
        axios.post(url, {
            usuario_id: this.usuario_id,
            email: this.email,
            celular: this.celular,
            codigo: this.codigo,
            estado: this.estado
        });

        if(this.estado == '2')
            $("#ocultaEstado").css("display", "block");
        else{
            $("#ocultaEstado").css("display", "none");
        }
    }
```

En la vista de administrador tiene lo siguiente

```
 <td>
   <a href="/cambiarEstado/1/{{$usuario->id}}"><span class="badge badge-primary">APROBAR</span></a>
   <a href="/cambiarEstado/2/{{$usuario->id}}"><span class="badge badge-danger">DESAPROBAR</span></a>
                        </td>
```

En web.php:

```
Route::get('cambiarEstado/{estado}/{id}', 'AdminController@cambiarEstado');
```

En el controlador

```
public function cambiarEstado($estado, $id){
    Acceso::where('id', $id)->update(['estado' => $estado]);

    //Usamos broadcast
    $message = 'Usuario verificado!';
    $user = User::find(Auth::id());
    event (new ChatEvent ($message, $user));

    // return redirect('/admin');
    return back();
}
```

Y en la vista del usuario, uso vue para escuchar el evento

```
mounted(){
        Echo.private('my-chat')
        .listen('ChatEvent', (e) => {
            window.location.href = '/cargaMails/' + this.usuario_id;
        });
    },
```

En la parte del usuario funciona correctamente, el problema es que también me redirige al usuario administrador a la vista

```
window.location.href = '/cargaMails/' + this.usuario_id;
```

No entiendo lo que está sucediendo y cómo puedo resolverlo. Agradecería mucho algo de luz sobre este asunto.

Comment: No sé si llego a entender bien lo que estás haciendo, pero si el administrador es el que puede enviar un request a la función `cambiarEstado`, cuando haces `$user = User::find(Auth::id());`, el usuario afectado va a ser el administrador, que es el que corresponde a  `Auth::id()`

Comment: En realidad ese fragmento no tiene nada que ver, lo utilice para que sólo un administrador pueda cambiar el estado. Pero en esa parte carece de sentido y lo deje así dado que ya estaba programado para otra cosa, pero lo voy a remover. Perdón si te desconcertó esa parte.

Comment: Yo te diría que el problema va por declarar el nombre del canal en duro `my-chat`. Debiera ser un canal único para el usuario e.g `chat_${$usuario->id}`. Y cuando hagas broadcast en el backend, armar el mismo nombre para responder

Comment: Ya lo resolví cambiando el mounted por update. Agradezco tu compromiso suena lógico lo que comentas también. Muchas gracias!